# Пунктуация в "Более чем"

Tags: пунктуация

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выдержка из книжки Е. В. Гейне "Кто убил Моцарта?" 2002 г. издания.

В середине абзаца в начале предложения автор употребляет "Более чем", отделяя "более" запятой. Чем это обусловлено?

Answer (score 3):

**Более чем вероятно** (запятая в этом выражении не ставится - это можно проверить поиском по книгам), это *ошибка* переводчика в сочетании с просмотром корректора. Предложение построено не по-русски (*что некто **был тем, кто сделал** то-то*), и его можно было исправить так:

> Весьма вероятно, что именно ван Свитен уговорил всех повернуть назад.

Comment: А что, первоначальная конструкция нелепа и неупотребима? (Некто был тем, кто сделал что-то)?

Comment: Её можно понять, но так не говорят носители языка, на который сделан перевод, - нарушены принципы перевода: не следует воспроизводить  буквально грамматические конструкции языка оригинала, если естественная речь в результате становится неестественной.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, автор текста руководствовался [общим правилом](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_68) и подразумевал сравнение вероятностей: *Более (146%), чем вероятно (10%), что...*, но мог ошибиться.

У "более чем" без запятой такие значения:

- совершенно, в высшей степени
- примерно, приблизительно (обычно со счётным оборотом)

"Совершенно вероятно" - странный оборот. Вероятность же не счётная, но "более чем вероятно" образует один член предложения со значением "очень вероятно".

Comment: Что за 146 и 10%?

Comment: Два числа для иллюстрации.

Comment: Не понимаю, о чём вы.